# Strange Language in the Login Screen for Unity and GNOME

Tags: 13.04, login-screen

I use my Ubuntu system in the French language while I type with an English keyboard layout. To my surprise, my login screen (dates and day etc) contains text which looks like Arabic (it might be Persian too, but I am not sure).

I searched for Arabic installation in the Synaptic package list, but no there was no such package! How did Arabic happen to the French system?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your language you can follow this steps:

```
sudo su
dpkg-reconfigure console-data
pkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
service keyboard-setup restart
```

Sometimes (ubuntu login screen for me) just running `dpkg-reconfigure console-data` is not sufficient.